# How to trap SQL warning message 'Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.' in profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, trace, profiler

I am hitting the 'Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.' and I want to run a trace on the statement that is getting that message.  The issue at hand is the 'statement' is a call to a stored procedure which in turn can call up to 10 other stored procedures.  I know the issue is a SUM or MIN/MAX that is occurring and was hoping i can just run a sql trace to identify the warning.

What events do i need to set to find the 'Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.' in the profiler?  I go to search for 'warning' in the textdata column and I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found it.  It displays as 'User Error Message'